# UIScrollView is unable to scroll

Tags: swift, xcode, uiscrollview, autolayout, scrollview

I have a scroll view, then inside the scroll view I have a view, and then lastly I have a text view inside the view. I turned off scrolling on the text view so that the more a user types the bigger the text view gets. I then gave trailing, leading, and top constraints to the scroll view. After that I set the view inside the scroll view to 0,0,0,0 for its frame and then I gave top, bottom, trailing, and leading to the text view. Lastly I set the the views width equal to the superview and the scroll view height equal to the view inside of it. In theory when a user types and it goes to a new line the view should get bigger and since the scroll view and view have equal heights the scroll view should also get bigger. However when I go to a new line the view gets bigger but I am unable to scroll, no scroll bar, nothing. Heres some screenshots of the constraints:[image]
[image]

Comment: imo you should share your codes rather than screen shot and need to more focus what you want to do exactly.

Comment: I don't have any code, the issue I am trying to solve is all in storyboards. What I want to do is have the same functionality as when you go to post something on twitter.

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out...
The scrollview height and the view can't be equal, the view should be larger than the scroll view or else there's no point in having the scroll view.